# Draw polygon in AndEngine GLES2 anchor center

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine GLES2 anchor center. I am trying to create a simple Polygon without using any physics engine (because i don't need physics). However, I can't find how to do this. I did find some extensions for GLES2 (https://github.com/recastrodiaz/AndEngine) but these are not supported by the anchor center branch.

This seems like a very basic thing that should be possible. Anybody that can tell me how to draw a simple polygon in AndEngine?

Comment: There is a mesh class for that. Read more about it here: https://books.google.pl/books?id=QCbUxHcYLskC&pg=PT137&lpg=PT137&dq=andengine+mesh+example&source=bl&ots=hl8uk1K6nD&sig=JkSR39OE6IzRFYpk9f513oFTplw&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=sMFkVeGdDIOiyAPQ44CoCA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=andengine%20mesh%20example&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided it was a better idea to just create a rectangle (for registering the touch events) and just add a sprite (which was a polygon) to this rectangle. It did not provide me any benefit by creating a touch area that was exactly the size and shape of the sprite, hence this method is the right solution for me. This would be a different story if I used physics, but I am not.